# Ubuntu 22.04 Bluetooth - reduce mouse lag - fix Delay and timeout

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, touchpad, mouse-pointer

Since updating from 20.04 to 22.04, my mouse feels much slower.

I made a slowmo video with my phone proofing there is a big delay between moving physical mouse and the cursor moving.
The delay is much smaller when using thelaptop integrated touchpad.

To resolve this, some person suggested editiing the Connection parameters of /var/lib/bluetooth/1C:C1:0C:45:EA:15/C0:4C:35:4E:86:37/info

```
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=9
Latency=44
Timeout=216
```

to sth like 6,7,0,216

When i do this, save the file and restart my BlueTooth service (service bluetooth restart
), the settings are back to the old ones.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to write to may be owned by `root`, as a system file.

If you are certain you are making safe changes, you can "elevate your current user account to have root privileges":

1. `sudo -v`

- switch user to root privileges.

2. **(Enter root password)**
3. `nano /some/system/file`

- You can also use your preferred text editor in place of `nano`. There is also `gedit`, Gnome's default GUI text editor.
- You are now editing the above file with the permissions to save as the `root` user.

4. **Save**
5. `systemctl restart bluetooth`

- restart your bluetooth service and load the new settings.

6. `exit`

- switch back to user privileges.